# Background Service with Notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, background-service

I am developing an Android application which calls API's to fetch data. Now I want to perform this task in background and each time data is changed in the List view, a notification should be generated.

How can I achieve this?

How can I make my API called in background and how can i generate notification. 
I am new to Services and BroadcastReceivers so help me

I am calling the service this way:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra("Background",true));
```

I created this code to testing purpose. To check if notifications can be called in background even if the app is closed.

My Service Class

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private Boolean isShowingNotification = true ;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


    if (intent.hasExtra("Background")) {
        if (isShowingNotification) {
            StopImportantJob();
            stopSelf();
        } else
            DoImportantJob();
    } else {
        DisplayNotification("Now showing the demo");
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Create Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}

public void DisplayNotification(String message){

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(message)
            .setContentText("Touch to off Service")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0,notification);

}

public void DoImportantJob(){

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
            .setContentText("Subject")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .build();

    startForeground(1992, notification);
    isShowingNotification =true;
}

public void StopImportantJob(){

    stopForeground(true);
    isShowingNotification = false;
    if(false){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ){
            stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH);
            stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE);

        }

    }
}

}
```

What I believe I should do is listed below, please correct me if I am wrong.

1. Start Service in the onCreate() of the MainAcitivity of Application.
2. In the Service call I will create a method which will do the API call.
3. On notifyDataSetChanged(); will call the Notification method.
4. Now here is the question: In Service class the API method will be called in onCreate() or  onStartCommand().

Comment: You should show a bit more context with your code and any errors that may have occurred so people can help you better

Comment: Did you searched in Stack Overflow? Because all questions you are doing are already solved searching a little in SO.

Comment: i am new so i don't know how to use services. Can anyone of you provide me a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to perform this task in background and each time data is
>   changed in the List view, a notification should be generated. How can
>   i achieve this? How can i make my API called in background and how can
>   i generate notification.

First Decide, whether you want this operation when your application is in `Foreground` OR `Background`. Now, `if Foreground`, you might not want to use `Service` class and use `AsyncTask` instead for making your webservice calls and generate the notification and updatethe listview once task is done. `If Background`, you can create `IntentService` and do your API operation there. However, in background mode, your application do not need to be notified as your app will not be visible to client.

Comment: I am confused,, what do you this which one is the best approach?

Comment: I believe i need to use the Background Service to do it. Can you tell me how can i do this? any good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand Wolt delivery app has always active notifications category in background whitch you can deactivate. [Notifications setup... Wolt app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqePS.jpg)